# Concordancia de número con la preposición "en"

Tags: diferencias-regionales, preposiciones, número-gramatical, concordancia-gramatical

La preposición "en" se puede usar para indicar cómo va uno vestido. Por ejemplo, "estar en pijama". Recientemente, mi hijo mayor (que ya es un experto navegando por YouTube Kids) descubrió una serie de animación titulada "[PJ Masks](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/PJ_Masks)", que en Hispanoamérica se le dio el nombre de "Héroes en pijamas".

Personalmente, a mí me suena mejor la expresión "héroes en pijama", por lo que me preguntaba si la preposición "en" usada de esta forma necesita concordancia de número cuando el objeto al que se refiere está en plural. ¿Es así? ¿O es simplemente un caso de diferencia regional?

Comment: Creo que no tiene que ver con que el sujeto sea plural. Buscando referencias he visto que usan "en pijamas" hablando de una sola persona: _Megan salió en “pijamas”_ o _Leonardo, sin pensarlo dos veces salió en pijamas_ y así bastantes ejemplos

Comment: @blonfu es una de las opciones que barajaba. Puedes plasmarlo como respuesta si quieres.

Comment: He encontrado sobre todo la frase en periódicos y blogs, hay 7 coincidencias en el CREA, en el CORDE ninguna. No sé en que paises se usa ni si es la forma habitual. Habría que investigar un poco más

Comment: I wonder whether the specific example may be due to the baleful influence of English? We only use _pyjamas_ as a plural.

Comment: @mdewey Good point. The word comes from English so it's possible. I found in the [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=pijama):  _En español no deben usarse las formas con -s para el singular: el pijamas._

Comment: "**En cueros**", "**en pelota**" y "**en pelotas**" también se pueden utilizar hablando de una sola persona.

Comment: Me parece bien lo que dicen @pablodf76 y Krauss al respecto, pero agrego un comentario, a mi aviso, "Héroes en Pijama" sería un mejor título, no importa la región donde uno se encuentre, para evitar la repetición de la S final.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El uso de la preposición **"en"** no require estrictamente la concordancia de número. El que se use en plural recae principalmente en el hecho de que **"pajamas/pyjamas"** se usa en plural en inglés (ver comentarios de @mdewey y @blonfu). Por otro lado, en general, el atuendo se compone de dos piezas; por lo cual su uso en plural está justificado (además, en el norte de México es raro que se use en singular aún cuando el [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=pijama) *prohibe* su uso).

Enfocándonos en la preposición **"de"**, existen muchos usos en los cuales, la forma correcta es el plural. Por ejemplo:

1. Mi hermana salió **en** huaraches.
2. El acróbata camina **en** zancos.
3. Mi hermano se metió **en** problemas.

En la lista anterior evité los posibles usos donde hay concordancia; aunque no necesariamente una correspondencia biunívoca:

1. Mis hermanas salieron **en** huaraches.
2. Los acróbatas caminan **en** zancos.
3. Mis hermanos están **en** problemas.

Por otro lado, la discordancia puede ser a la inversa:

1. Mis hermanas salieron **en** automóvil.
2. Todos salieron **en** chaqueta de cuero.
3. Pollitos **en** fuga (traducción al español en Latinoamérica del título de la película Chicken Run)

Answer (score 2):

Hay unas cuantas palabras en español que tradicionalmente se han usado en plural: prendas de ropa sobre todo (pantalones, pijamas, calzones, enaguas) pero también objetos que se componen de dos partes iguales (tijeras, anteojos, pinzas, tenazas). En algunos dialectos se usan más en plural, en otros se tiende más al singular.

El uso de dichos sustantivos con la preposición "de" o "en" es idiomático. No se trata de concordancia gramatical. En dialecto rioplatense se dice "dormir en pijama" o "salir de pantalón" pero esto no tiene que ver con las preposiciones, ya que también se dice "compré un pijama nuevo" y "me puse el pantalón" (y si se habla de "pijamas" o "pantalones" queda claro que se trata de un verdadero plural, es decir, varios pijamas o varios pantalones).